# Is there a way in C# to "type" a long?

Tags: c#

I use a long as the primary key in my tables. I have a data object for each table that has a DataObject.Select(long primarykey).

It would be nice if I could type that long so that I don't pass the PK for table1 into the Select() for table2. This would eliminate the common error where the wrong foreign key is being passed in.

I'm guessing no way other than wrapping the long in a class but I figured it can't hurt to ask. Is there a way to do this where at runtime it's still passing a long (the primitive type) but at compile time it'll flag mis-matches?

```
public class Subscription {
    public long SubscriptionId { get; }
    public long OrganizationId { get; }

    public static Subscription Select (long subscriptionId) {}
}

public class Organization {
    public long OrganizationId { get; }
    public static Organization Select (long organizationId) {}
}
```

In the above any long can be passed in. But if I am calling:

```
Organization org = Organization.Select(subscription.SubscriptionId);
```

that compiles and runs. But it's wrong. I would prefer to get a compile error on that as the correct call is:

```
Organization org = Organization.Select(subscription.OrganizationId)
```

Comment: Personally, I need to see some concrete code to understand what you're asking. You mention two tables, but what exactly are you doing with these two tables?

Comment: Please show us some code, where you try to use this.

Comment: @Jacob - example added

Comment: I dont think, that is necessary. But you might write an [Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2017) that performs the check and generates a warning.

Comment: If you're too worried about doing that mistake, I would add an overload to each of the `Select` methods that takes a `Subscription`/`Organization` parameter. That way, you have the option to either do `.Select(99)` or [`.Select(subscription)` and `.Select(organization)`].

Comment: In other words, when you're passing a "plain number", you can use the original methods, but when you need to pass the ID that is a member of a `Subscription` or an `Organization` object, you can use the overload methods and pass the objects themselves _rather than `SubscriptionId` and `OrganizationId`_. Then, of course, in the method body, you would get the appropriate ID of the object and proceed (e.g., by simply calling the original method and passing the _right_ ID to it).

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed - thank you, I might do that. There are numerous different combinations of classes but to your point, not a big deal to just have a bunch of methods that take the object and then call the Select() that does the work. If you post that as an answer I'm happy to then mark it the solution.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest, you create two structures, each with a `public long` Field, then you should define your methods to use those two different structures as parameters. Then if you get it wrong, the compiler will tell you.

Comment: I agree. `public struct SubscriptionId { … }` and `public struct OrganizationId { … }`. Each `struct` contains only one non-static field, namely `long Id`. One could consider making each of these `struct` immutable (then the field should be `private` and/or `readonly`, and not be modified by any method or property). In any case, when the program runs, as requested by the asker, _at runtime it's still passing a long_.

Comment: I agree with the idea here but do not make it a public long. Make it private, and then make user-defined explicit conversions to and from long.